# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #botao_resp_<?=$row['id']?>

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

tenho uma página com formularios para responder perguntas e estou tentando utilizar jquery em um arquivo separado e está dando o seguinte erro:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #botao_resp_

```
$("#botao_resp_<?=$row['id']?>").on('click', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
alert('Você clicou no botão!');

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url : 'banco-responder.php',
    data: {
    id : $("#id-resposta-<?=$row['id']?>").val() ,
    resposta : $("#resposta-pergunta-<?=$row['id']?>").val()
}
    }).done(function(data){
    console.log($("#card-<?=$row['id']?>").hide());
    alert("Respondido com Sucesso!");
    }).fail(function(){
    alert('Deu pau');
    });
return false;

});
```

No atributo ID dos formulários é completado por uma variável , que vem da iteração um array.
Quando eu coloco este código no mesmo arquivo dos formulários, ele funciona. Mas quando importo ele de outro arquivo ele não funciona.

Comment: Esse código `JS` fica em um arquivo de javascript separado?

Comment: Sim, este arquivo fica separado.

Comment: Bem, é possível, mas não é recomendado. Você pode "informar" para o seu servidor `Nginx/Apache` ler o JS como se fosse um PHP, porém isso gera graves problemas de segurança; Você pode criar um código `PHP` para se comportar como JS, basta adicionar o `header => Content-Type: text/javascript` ou você pode criar uma variável global em `form.html`, por exemplo e utiliza-la no arquivo `.js`.

Comment: teria outra solução que não fosse essa? o problema está na variável php, né?

Comment: O problema está em utilizar `php` nos arquivos `.js`. Os servidores, por padrão, não interpreta o código `php` nesses arquivos. Se possível poste parte do seu `html gerado` para que eu possa postar uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: <form id="form_ocul_<?=$row['id']?>" style="display: inline-block;" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="id-ocultar-<?=$row['id']?>" name="id" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">OCULTAR</button>
</form>
Este é um dos formulários. O ajax estava logo abaixo e coloquei em outro arquivo.

Comment: Acredito que a melhor solução para isso é unir esse código js à um arquivo .php